# Extract information from a String once matches

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like:

```
var display=@("every (Name=Event(HostInfo='HostName',UserInfo='UserName'))");
```

This string may change and may not always start with **every (Name=**, but always that contains *HostInfo* or *UserInfo* would be in the way showed. I would need to extract the information of HostName and UserName. 
Let's say for example that other time display string could be:

```
var display=@("Event(UserInfo='UserName'))");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the order of `Hostname` and `Username` fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would run it twice as two regex's like:

```
string UserInfoPattern = @"UserInfo='(?<UserInfo>[^']+)";
string HostInfoPattern = @"HostInfo='(?<HostInfo>[^']+)";
```

That way your regex would not break if the ordering was switched.

Answer (score 1):

User regular expressions. The simplest case is

```
string pattern1 = @"HostInfo='(?<HostInfo>[^']*)'";
string pattern2 = @"UserInfo='(?<UserInfo>[^']*)'";
```